# Is there a way not to do Popup animation?

Tags: python, kivy

In kivy popup, I see that I can control whether it would do the animation or not by declaring

`popup.open(animation=False)` or `popup.dismiss(animation=False)`

However, when I am not manually controlling the open and dismiss, I can't find a way to not do the animation.

**Here is some code from `ModalView`,**

**which is a parent class for `Popup`**

```
def dismiss(self, *largs, **kwargs):
    '''Close the view if it is open. If you really want to close the
    view, whatever the on_dismiss event returns, you can use the *force*
    argument:
    ::

        view = ModalView()
        view.dismiss(force=True)

    When the view is dismissed, it will be faded out before being
    removed from the parent. If you don't want animation, use::

        view.dismiss(animation=False)

    '''
    if self._window is None:
        return
    if self.dispatch('on_dismiss') is True:
        if kwargs.get('force', False) is not True:
            return
    if kwargs.get('animation', True):
        Animation(_anim_alpha=0., d=self._anim_duration).start(self)
    else:
        self._anim_alpha = 0
        self._real_remove_widget()
```

Like I have mentioned, I can do `popup.dismiss(animation=False)` to not run animation. However, I can't find a way to put a parameter in when I do auto dismiss(touching outside of the popup).

Is there a way to do so without touching `ModalView` source itself?

> Summary: how do I not do animation when I auto dismiss a pop up?

Comment: There is no "approved" way of doing that, but you might try setting `popup._anim_duration = 0.0` after you create the `Popup`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this problem by inheriting `dismiss()` from `ModalView`

```
class PopupNoAnimation(Popup):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(PopupNoAnimation, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def dismiss(self, *largs, **kwargs):
        if self._window is None:
            return
        if self.dispatch('on_dismiss') is True:
            if kwargs.get('force', False) is not True:
                return

        self._anim_alpha = 0
        self._real_remove_widget()
```

Now, `dismiss` doesn't create an `Animation` object, which results in no animation on dismiss.